# Can't log into Wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, authentication

Hello there you beautiful people :)

I just recently moved my website from the development subdomain (dev.melliandshayne.com) to my live domain (www.melliandshayne.com) and for some reason, I cannot log in to my wordpress dashboard the easy way.

What i mean is, whenever I try to put in my credentials (and they are correct), the login page simply refreshes - still showing me to put in the username and password.

The ONLY way I can access the dashboard is to click "Forgot your password", fill in my email address, click send and then it tells me to check my email to reset the password. But, it also displays the inputs for Username & password again - and from there, I can login with my credentials.

I dont even know where to begin to look. and I'd be happy to provide temp. access if needed, as well as any information I can find.

Huge thank you to anyone who is able to help... or atleast, try :)

Comment: Have you tried another browser or clearing your cookies? I've had issues in the past where an old rogue cookie was the issue.

Comment: I just tried loggin in on Safari, and on an incognito window of chrome :( Same thing... :(

Comment: How did you transfer the page to your live domain? Have checked your .htaccess file as well as rewritten the db to your new domain?

Comment: I basically l created a new public_html folder in the root of my domain but called it public_html_new. Copied all the contents from my dev site to it and then updated the links in the database. Then I simply renamed teh current public_html to public_html_old and remove the _new from the newly created one. That was recommended to me by my Host... As far as the .htaccess, i have not checked it :( I dont know what I should be checking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: 
So, I had a plugin installed called Peter's Login Redirect as I have users who log in to my website and need to be directed to their specific section. It turns out I completely forgot to set a rule for the Admins to enter the Dashboard. A simple fix. Found in the Settings of Peters login redirect.